# How can I eagerly load an answers latest revision?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Q&A site and it allows answers to be changed while storing a revision of each change, much like here on Stackoverflow.  When selecting some answers, I'd like it to include the most recent(but not all) revision as a property of each answer, so that I can avoid doing n+1 queries on my page.

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    problem = models.ForeignKey(Problem)

class AnswerRevision(models.Model):
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, related_name='revisions')
    text = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()


Answer.objects.filter(problem=p)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following structure:

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    revision = models.ForeignKey(AnswerRevision)
    problem = models.ForeignKey(Problem)

class AnswerRevision(models.Model):
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, related_name='revisions')
    text = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

The only difference is that I added a `revision` property to the answer. When a new revision is made, just change the FK to point to the new revision.

Comment: I was hoping to keep it fully normalized, but I'll do this if I can't find a better way.